# String unknown Eclipse

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8

I've changed the encoding from Eclipse but all my strings with special characters now are like this "�". The old encoding was the Default (Cp1252), now it is UTF-8. How can I fix the strings with special characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, imagine you switch your brain to only understand Chinese. Could you read an English text anymore?

You changed the way Eclipse interprets the bits of your sourcecode. So you need to translate the sourcecode from Cp1252 to UTF-8.

I don't know if Eclipse is able to do this, but Notepad++ is.

Open a java-file you want to change the encoding of in Notepad++.
Click on `Encoding`
Select `Convert to UTF-8`
Save the file

When you now click on `Encoding` again, there should be a dot in front of `Encode in UTF-8`

Edit: Notepad++ recognizes the used encoding, so you can read it there. Copy and Paste from Notepad++ to Eclipse won't work, because you copied the same string Eclipse couldn't read. You have to change the encoding of the string.

Comment: I opened a java file which was with some � in the Notepad++ and it was normal, but I have too many classes to copy from to Notepad++ e paste back in the Eclipse :(

Comment: That's no problem, I'll expand my answer.

Comment: This method is the easiest I know.